# Startup with Django runserver error

Tags: python, django, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I am starting up with Python-Django in Ubuntu 18.04.

I have python3 installed.

`python3 --version` says `Python 3.5.2`

After installing Python, I installed Django as below:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install django
```

I also have Django installed.

`django-admin --version` says `2.0.5`

In my project, **startproject** worked successfully, but when I am trying to run the following command inside my project:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

It gives following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Following command also gives error:

```
python3 -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
```

Error is:

```
python3 -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

`which django` gives blank output

`echo $PYTHONPATH` gives blank output

`python3 -m django --version` says `/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named django`

`echo $PATH` shows `/home/shobhit/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

What is the problem and what is the solution here?

**Update**

`ls /usr/local/lib | grep` python says

> libpython3.5m.a
>
> python3.5
>
> python3.6

Comment: can you check exactly where the django module installed? you can check by using pip list (For python2) and pip3 list (for python3). By default that may be pointing to python2. So you can start the project.

Comment: @JishnunandPk pip3 list shows Django (2.0.5) in the list. 
But it doesnot show the location of installation.

Comment: To make sure a module is installed to a specific version of python, use `python3.6 -m pip install django`. Also, to make sure pip is installed to the right python version, download `[get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)` and execute it using the desired python version.

Comment: is there any version dependancy like in python3.5 or 3.6 like that?

Comment: I suggest to create virtual env using python3 `virtualenv -p python3 venv` , activate it  `source venv/bin/activate` and then install all requirements inside it `pip install -r requirments.txt`

Comment: You need to configure your $PYTHONPATH, something like this: 
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_PYTHON_FOLDER>/site-packages/ 
export PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is problem with the path.

I **strongly recommend** using virtual environment for all django development.

You can follow this process:

**Install pip3**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

**Install Virtual Environment for Python3**

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

**Create a project directory**

```
mkdir ~/newproject
cd ~/newproject
```

**Create a new virtual environemnt and activate it**

```
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

**Now Install Django**

```
pip install django
```

and then **create project and start** it,

```
django-admin startproject my_project

cd my_project

python manage.py runserver
```

It should work this way.

Comment: Should I use pip install Django or pip3 install Django?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be Django-admin startproject my_project instead of python manage.py startproject my_project

Comment: @ITSagar, yeah it was a mistake it should be `django-admin`.

Comment: @ITSagar, inside virtual environment only you need to do `pip install django`.

Comment: The project worked fine yesterday. But now when I have restarted my machine, the project has again started giving the old error. Do I need to do anything on machine reboot?

Comment: You have forgit to activate the environment, just activate your virtual environment and try it again . It should work fine. `source .venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Hi, so I will need to activate the virtual environment on every reboot? The how will such issue be resolved in a live environment?

Comment: You have to activate the environment before running project. In the live environment virtual environment is always activated.

Answer (score 0):

I also found if you are using PyCharm, you can go to configuration -> 
for manage.py add runserver 8080 to your parameters, and this will work when you run manage.py via Pycharm start button.

Another solution for my specific machine was to just restart it and re-run pycharm, typing in terminal **python manage.py runserver 8080**, worked for me.
This is after I had the same exact error.....very annoying and mind boggling.

Answer (score 0):

First Check whether you are in the same directory if not then type
Cd /c/ your folder name then enter
Then go for python manage. Py runserver hope it will work